# Using a redux/flux like global state

Tags: android, redux, flux

I am currently trying to learn the principles of `redux/flux` and how they can be implemented in `Android`. What don't I get is how the principle of only one global store/state should be implemented in an `Android` application? Are there any best practices for this, especially regarding saving and restoring after orientation changes and after the `Android` system decided to free up memory?

The only solution I thought is applicable is using the `ViewModel` Class from the `Android` architectural components. But that isn't really a global state, only per Activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to keep the state in the application class. This will survive context changes, and terminate together with the application.

If you don't want to bother with extending the application class then a global static class/reference will do.

Comment: But I've read that the Application class can be destroyed/recreated by the system at any time and there is no saveinstance method as far as I know. How would you recreate the state after such a destroy/restore happened?

Comment: Save persistent state to disk.  You can restore the state during application onCreate().  For non persistent state use activities saveinstance to save state which has changed.  Restore during application onCreate() only.  Unfortunately no way to know when your app will get destroyed/recreated.  Alternatively you can just use react-native with redux so you don't have to worry about this.

Comment: Actually you still have to worry about it for react-native, but you do get [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist) which makes saving state easier.